# Download Google Drive file from ASP.NET to user's browser default dialog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to download a Google Drive file to the user's default download folder using ASP.NET, MVC, Google Drive API V2, authenticating via Service Account.

The examples I've seen use a _saveTo path and file name.  I don't want the user to have to specify this information before initiating the download.  I just want the user to click on a file in web app and have it display the browser download dialog.  Is this possible?

Here are the 3 layers:

CSHTML

```
<td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "GoogleDrive", new { _fileId = item.DriveId })">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.FileName)</a>
</td>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string _fileId)
{
    GoogleDrivePageVM vm = new GoogleDrivePageVM();

    // Get Service
    DriveService _service = GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveAPI.GoogleDriveAuthentication();

    // Download File
    File _file = GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveAPI.GetFile(_service, _fileId);

    bool _success = GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveAPI.DownloadFile(_service, _file, null);     // _saveTo);  

    return RedirectToAction("GoogleDriveList", "GoogleDrive");
}
```

SERVICE LAYER

```
public static Boolean DownloadFile(DriveService _service, File _file, string _saveTo)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_file.DownloadUrl))
    {
    try
    {
        var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_file.DownloadUrl);
        byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c://myFirstDownload.txt", arrBytes);    //_saveTo
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return false;
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm trying to implement the wrong approach.  Can someone clarify whether this is even possible and point me in the right direction.  Can I just use the file's downloadURL from the web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download URL you're looking for is called [webContentlink](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) in Drive API which is generated using [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get).

> **webContentLink** A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in
>   Drive.

This link will allow you to download files straight from the browser.

Use [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#try-it) to test it now.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.  Under what condition would I want to use my original approach?